# Socket doesn't communicate with other networks

Tags: python, sockets, networking

Im trying to send a 8 digit pin code from one computer to another, the code works when both of the computers are on the same networks.But there seems to be a problem when they are not on the same network. it just doesnt send the pin to the server pc.

receives the data from the client and saves it
server.py

```
import socket
import json
import Classes


def recive_pin(s_data):
    pin = s_data.recv(int(s_data.recv(1).decode())).decode()
    return pin


def main():
    # gets port from json file
    with open("Config.JSON", 'r') as f:
        json_data = json.load(f)
        port = json_data["load"]["port"]
    # create the tcp socket
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    # binds the socket to localhost , config port number
    ip = '0.0.0.0'
    s.bind((ip, port))
    user_data = {}
    while 1:
        s.listen()
        s_data, address = s.accept()
        command = s_data.recv(1).decode()
        if command == "P":
            user_data[recive_pin(s_data)] = address
            print(user_data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

client.py
create a 8 digit code and sends it to the server

```
import socket
import json

import Classes


def main():
    # gets the user input controlled/controller.


    with open("Config.JSON", 'r') as f:
        json_data = json.load(f)
        port = json_data["load"]["port"]
        ip = json_data["load"]["ip"]

    c = Classes.handler(ip, port)
    x = Classes.pin.create_pin()

    c.send_pin(x)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Classes.py

```
import random
import string
import socket


class handler:
    def __init__(self, comunication_ip=0, port=0, ):
        self.__comunication_ip = comunication_ip
        self.__port = int(port)

        # type of command to send to the server

        # tuple of the server details
        self.__server_details = (self.__comunication_ip, self.__port)

    def send_pin(self, verification_pin):
        # command type : Send_pin("P")
        command_type = "P"
        # creates a socket to send the pin to the server
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        # adds the type of the command and the length of the pin to the Pin.

        msg = command_type + str(len(verification_pin)) + verification_pin

        s.connect(self.__server_details)
        s.send(msg.encode())




class pin:
    @staticmethod
    # def __init__(self, defult_pin=0):
    #    self.__pin = defult_pin

    def create_pin():
        characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
        verification_pin = str(''.join(random.choice(characters) for length in range(8)))
        return str(verification_pin)
```

i also use a Json file to save the port number and the server ip :

{
"load":{
"ip":"10.100.102.94",
"port": 12000
}
}

Comment: Do you get an error? Post it. But likely a router/firewall issue and not code.

Comment: it does not show a Erorr.
(when i run netstat -a 
it shows the port as listening )